what is the common reasong of nginx not passing request to php
In the application, we start seeing a lot of the 504 requests from Nginx, but in most cases, we see only Nginx log about the fact of 504 due to the 60-second timeout but no logs from the PHP/FPM side. We still have application logs for some 504-related endpoints and in most of the cases it's because of some non-optimized/heavy db query, but most 504 responses are without application logs (only Nginx) at all and I can't debug/understand what the issue is.
My first thought was log buffer, as we also have a timeout on the fpm side (which is the same 60 seconds) so PHP is not sending buffered logs because of interruption: but we have a stream logger, and also for some 60s 504 requests we have logs, so that idea was rejected.
The second idea was not enough PHP workers, we have
pm: static
pm_max_children: 30

but we have Prometheus metrics and they show that the maximum amount of active processes is 15, so it's far away from 30. Also, we have HPA, configured to start new pods when any pod reaches 50% of active workers.
Depending on K8s resources metrics all look good, with no spikes in terms of resources (CPU/memory). What else can be the issue here, where do I need to look?

What you are asking in the body of your post appears to be unrelated to the title of your post. If nginx cannot pass the request to PHP it will respond with a 503 error.
A 504 is a timeout error.

in most of the cases it's because of some non-optimized/heavy db query

So there's a database here too? Aren't you checking its logs?
Instrument your PHP to capture log data during execution and/or run a profiler on your environment.

okay, for example, I have 2 requests /v1/api/products/1, for both requests, I see the Nginx log with 504 responses and an execution time equal to 60 seconds. But for the first log I see application logs: 1) route matched 2) execution passed to handler 3) db query execution started and that is it,  which means that after the db query execution started, the request was interrupted due to timeout. But for the second request which is the same request with the same product id, I can see only a single 504 log from Nginx and no logs from the application.

That is the case for 80% of requests that finish with 504, that is why my assumption is that for some reason Nginx holds requests till the timeout and not passing to the application, otherwise how to explain that for some 504 requests I have application logs, and for other not

"Instrument your PHP to capture log data during execution and/or run a profiler on your environment." so issue here is that in most cases I can't capture logs or profile the request because app is not triggered and I do not know why
